# Why is my NSButton template image not working as such any more?

Tags: cocoa, nsbutton

I have some code that I wrote back on, I think, Leopard. There’s an NSButton with an image called DuckIconTemplate.png.

Originally, the button would be rendered with the image rendered with a nice inner shadow, and it would highlight blue when toggled on, because of the *Template name. However, when I build and run it now (very latest OS X version), the image on the button is rendered as-is and there’s no highlight when the button is toggled on.

Here’s a screenshot (left now, right screenshots from before): [image]

What gives?

I’ve checked in the debugger and the button’s .image -isTemplate returns YES.

The button is configured as such:

- Style: gradient
- Type: toggle
- Bordered
- Title: “Duck”
- Image: “DuckIconTemplate”
- Alternate image: (none)
- Image position: image only, centered

Comment: Were you ever able to find the cause?

Comment: @MichaelTeper no, I ended up creating images myself. I do believe that these templates will be making a return with Yosemite.